# SVG images are not display asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display svg image but it's not working.
My code:

```
<img src="~/Content/img/arrows.svg" alt="">
```

I tried:

```
<img src="../../Content/img/arrows.svg" alt="">
```

I also tried to define in the web confog

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svc" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

After a little more search i saw an option to solution. Adding Static Content MIME Mappings in the IIS [in this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)

Someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? At this stage it means you have not made any effort to understand your problem.

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the error? Are you sure the file is actually there? Can you access it in a browser on it's own?

Comment: I mean that i can't see the picture in the browser But because I was focused on the problem I forgot to use Ctrl F5 instead F5 for refresh the JS, CSS files.
Now everything working good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div and add the SVG image as the background-url in a CSS class.

In HTML

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%" class="custom-svg">
</div>
```

IN CSS

```
 .custom-svg {
  background: transparent url("../Images/note.svg") 
  no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```